# How to texture crowded building

Tags: texturing

I have made a crowd of buildings with the addon. Now I have to texture those buildings. The problem I have is to select each building, unwrap it and align the texture - huh, if it was a few 5-10 it would be ok. But it's more then 75 buildings! Is there any quick tip or addon available to wrap the texture on those buildings?

[image]

Comment: Which addon? I want it ;-)

Comment: @PHEDev name of the addon is GIS

Comment: http://www.creativeshrimp.com/how-to-create-a-city-covered-with-fog.html

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how detailed you want your textures.
Here are a few non accurate and fast methods:

## Copy the material

You can try to determine 4-8 types of buildings (skyscrapers, living houses, hospitals, schools etc), make textures for them and just copy-pasted a resulting material to the other buildings, depending on their types.

Select all meshes, the last one set up with a random texture of a skyscraper.
Then go to materials tab in properties, then copy the texture to other selected meshes.
After that, for each mesh: <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter edit mode, then <kbd>U</kbd> -> `Smart UV Project`.

[image: Copying a texture]

## One big mesh

You can connect all meshes into one (<kbd>A</kbd> to select, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them), <kbd>tab</kbd>, then <kbd>U</kbd> -> `Smart UV Project` and make one big texture for them. After that, you can tune them after unwrapping to get better result (e.g. scale properly; set up roofs if you have them in your texture, etc). After that, you can separate meshes. In edit mode <kbd>P</kbd> -> `by loose parts`. And you will get several buildings with the same texture.

Can't provide a gif here.
The gif is too big, you can [find it here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvEC6.jpg)

Comment: can u plz show how it works with screen shot or gif in detail